# Regular expression to match maximium of five words

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a regular expression

```
^[a-zA-Z+#-.0-9]{1,5}$
```

which validates that the word contains alpha-numeric characters and few special characters and length should not be more than `5` characters.

How do I make this regular expression to accept a maximum of five words matching the above regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[a-zA-Z+#\-.0-9]{1,5}(\s[a-zA-Z+#\-.0-9]{1,5}){0,4}$`

Also, you could use for example `[ ]` instead of `\s` if you just want to accept space, not tab and newline. And you could write `[ ]+` (or `\s+`) for any number of spaces (or whitespaces), not just one.

**Edit:** Removed the invalid solution and fixed the bug mentioned by unicornaddict.

Comment: No problem. Also, be aware of the bug mentioned by unicornaddict; I did not escape or move the hyphen like he did (until now).

Comment: I believe that last part of the patter {0,4} has a side affect of not allowing longer sentences so if the sentence has more than 9 words for example this won't match, right?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this may be what you're looking for. It forces at least one word of your desired pattern, then zero to four of the same, each preceded by one or more white-space characters:

```
    ^XX(\s+XX){0,4}$
```

where `XX` is your actual one-word regex.

It's separated into two distinct sections so that you're not required to have white-space at the end of the string. If you want to *allow* for such white-space, simply add `\s*` at that point. For example, allowing white-space both at start and end would be:

```
    ^\s*XX(\s+XX){0,4}\s*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You regex has a small bug. It matches letters, digits, `+`, `#`, `period` but not `hyphen` and also all char between `#` and `period`. This is because `hyphen` in a char class when surrounded on both sides acts as a range meta char. To avoid this you'll have to escape the `hyphen`:

```
^[a-zA-Z+#\-.0-9]{1,5}$
```

Or put it at the beg/end of the char class, so that its treated literally:

```
^[-a-zA-Z+#-.0-9]{1,5}$
^[a-zA-Z+#.0-9-]{1,5}$
```

Now to match a max of 5 such words you can use:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z+#\-.0-9]{1,5}\s+){1,5}$
```

**EDIT:** This solution has a severe limitation of matching only those input that end in white space!!! To overcome this limitation you can see the ans by Jakob.