# What regex expression will only allow one to 3 words?

Tags: c#, regex

I am doing a project in Visual Studio Windows Form with C#. I am attempting to validate the data in a textbox to only allow one, two or three words. Right now my code will allow two or more words, but not just one word. It will also not prevent more than 3 words. Can someone help me?

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]*[ ]{1}[A-Za-z]*[ ]{1}[A-Za-z]*");
if (!expression.Match(DescriptionTxtBox.Text).Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The description should be one, two or three words", "Invalid Format for Description", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    DescriptionTxtBox.Clear();
    DescriptionTxtBox.Focus();
    return; 
}
```

Comment: check it out the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605533/regular-expression-to-match-maximium-of-five-words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z]+\s*){1,3}$
```

`^` depicts start of the string

`$` depicts end of the string

`{n}` is a quantifier that matches exactly n times

`{n,}` at least n matches

`{n,m}` between n to m matches

`\s` represents space and is similar to `[\n\r\t\f]`

---

You should use the [IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx) method

Comment: Have you tried running it? With just looking at the regex, I would say that `[a-zA-Z]\s*` will match a *letter* followed by zero or more spaces. Perhaps you meant `[a-zA-Z]+\s*`?

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped explain the concept! However, it doesnt work.

Comment: @AbinThomas Try this: `^\s*([a-zA-Z]+\s*){1,3}$`

Comment: Is the first \s* necessary? Seems to me that it's not.

Comment: @BasTaller it would be required in case your input contain's space in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `String.Split` method to separate out your data, and then simply checking that the resulting array is of Length <= 3?

Note that this approach will allow empty strings to pass this test, so you should probably do a check for `String.IsNullOrEmpty` also.

Comment: If you don't want to check, you can use the overload that receives a 2nd parameter, and just pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: Im only allowed to use RegEx. Thanks for the help though!